# How to hide some size option from size swatches?

Tags: magento2

I have not programmatical experience, especially in magento2.

I wanted to hide some size options from size swatches on the product details page based on category.

Detail Issue Explanation:

Suppose I have a configurable product XYZ and it has 25,26,30,34,36,38,4 size option. and product falling in category A and category B. Now i wanted to hide size option < 36 size if user going through category B on product XYZ .

Note: Product XYZ is only one product and falling in two category.

Please provide the solution where and what i have to do.

Thanks in advance.